# Using socket.io to Connect with Elixir's Phoenix Sockets

Tags: sockets, elixir

Im trying to connect a Javascript client to a Elixir phoenix socket by using socket.io. Right now what Im doing is this:

```
var socket = io.connect('ws/ip.adress.of.server/ws');
```

However Im not getting a connected true socket object:

[image]

Can anyone guide me on the correct way to connect to the phoenix socket? Is there any place in my server code where I can look for the URL I need to connect to?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use the official [phoenix.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix) library? That will connect you to Phoenix without any issues. If you really want to use socket.io, maybe look at the [source for phoenix.js](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/web/static/js/phoenix.js) to see if there is anything extra you may be missing. Also, are you getting any errors on the server that may be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

socket.io is a dedicated protocol which works on top of websockets or long polling. It leverages similar concepts to those offered by phoenix sockets. But apart from that, those two are two distinct things which are not interoperable. As Justin Wood mentioned, use phoenix.js when you want to use phoenix channels.